# How to connect to a openVPN server using Google Colaboratory?

Tags: openvpn, google-colaboratory

When I run `!openvpn --config client.ovpn` on a Google Colaboratory notebook I get the error:

```
Mon Jan 22 19:38:53 2018 ROUTE_GATEWAY 172.17.0.1/255.255.0.0 IFACE=eth0 HWADDR=02:42:ac:11:00:02
Mon Jan 22 19:38:53 2018 ERROR: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such file or directory (errno=2)
Mon Jan 22 19:38:53 2018 Exiting due to fatal error
```

How to solve this?
Is it even possible to connect Google Colaboratory to a Virtual Private Server?
The file runs fine through my local pc.

This image shows the complete output (click for larger version):

[image: output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like local backends aren't presently supported, but work is in progress.
https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/29

Comment: Thank you for answering. I posted that github issue yesterday. Sorry forgot to relay their reply on stackexchange